# How to copy size data from admin fields to swatch fields

Tags: magento2, swatches

I like to use the plain-size data as a text swatch in the size attribute.

[image]

This size data is available in the admin fields.
We have too many articles to enter the swatch data manually.

I know there are some similar questions and answers.
Those answers are based on unique codes and scripts.
[ I have little knowledge or experience in that ]
I wonder, are there other options?

- Option check marks like "Use size data as swatch data"
- Import a CSV, linking size data to text swatch data
- Leaving a comparison table in some folder

Comment: just to understand better. let's take as example the third row (1.5 cm). you want to copy the value `1.5 cm` to the next 2 inputs? just like you have for the first 2 rows?

Answer (score 0):

In case I understood the question correctly and you want to copy the values from the admin description to the default store view swatch and description, you can just run these 2 lines in the console of your browser and then save the attribute.

Run them in this order.

```
jQuery("[name^=swatchtext\\[value\\]][name$=\\[1\\]]").each(function () {jQuery(this).val(jQuery(this).parent().prev().find('input').val())});
jQuery("[name^=optiontext\\[value\\]][name$=\\[1\\]]").each(function () {jQuery(this).val(jQuery(this).parent().prev().find('input').val())});
```